# How to pass codebehind value to HeaderTemplate label control of Gridview UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

In ASP.NET usign C#, .NET3.5 F/W

Hi,

I've a Gridview with template columns containing textbox and Label controls.

By code through some queries and stored procedures i got some data to a datatable. Now i want to pass  this datatable column field or names to the Gridview Label controls.

How can i set the datatable column header names to gridview label control of Header Template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called Binding [here is link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx)

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
         <ItemTemplate HeaderText="PersonId">
                <asp:Label id=Label1 runat="server"  
                   Text='<%# Eval("NameOfColumnt") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>   
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: @Lam: I've datatable column field names. Those field is want to set to GridView. For this how to do??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:TemplateColumn >
        <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label id=Label1 runat="server"  
                  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,EmployeeName") %>'>
               </asp:Label>

        </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Faheem: I updated my subject of the Question. Please provide for the same.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you will have to give your grid view a data source:

```
yourGridView.DataSource = yourDataTable;
yourGridView.DataBind();
```

After you do this, you just have to link each control in template columns to column in datatable, for example:

```
<HeaderTemplate>SomeText</HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="a" Text='<%# Eval("nameOfTheColumn") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

EDIT: 
Regarding your other question, I suggest you to add bound fields to your grid view dynamically rather then right away in the aspx. Something like this:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            BoundField nameColumn = new BoundField();
            nameColumn.DataField = column.ColumnName.ToString();
            nameColumn.SortExpression = column.ColumnName.ToString();
            nameColumn.HeaderText = column.ColumnName.ToString();

            gridView.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
        }
```

This way you don't have to know exactly how many columns you have, and have the ability to name them as they are in the data table.

Comment: Please see the updated subject of the Question. I want header template info. Assume i may have Dotnet or Java or Mainframe etc in the datatable column headers. Now those headers i want to set to Grid too...  Please help

Comment: @Markan- I doesn't need adding the columns. I have fixed count of columns. but from datatable i want to use those column header calues to gridview header

Comment: You will still need to add columns dynamically to give them custom header text if I'm not mistaken. Read this: [link]http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/create_template_columns.aspx?display=Print